# Can we define 'model' to mean 'diagram' in the sense of mathematical logic? If so, how to define the satisfaction relation?

Tags: logic, model-theory

[According](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_%28mathematical_logic%29#Theories_associated_with_a_structure) to Wikipedia, every $\sigma$-structure $A$ is associated with a collection of atomic and negated atomic sentences called its *diagram*. Here's the precise definition.

> For each σ-structure $A$, there are several associated theories in a
>   larger signature σ' that extends σ by adding one new constant symbol
>   for each element of the domain of A... The *diagram* of $A$ consists of
>   all atomic or negated atomic σ'-sentences that are satisfied by $A$
>   and is denoted by $\mathrm{diag}_A$.

I was wondering. Since the diagram apparently captures everything about the structure, could we in principle define that a mathematical structure *is* its diagram? Or better yet, an ordered triple $(X,\sigma,D),$ where $D$ is the diagram in the larger signature $\sigma'$.

If so, then **question**: How do we define the notion that a structure satisfies a theory? In particular, how do we define $(X,\sigma,D) \models (T,\sigma),$ where $T$ is a deductively-closed first order theory in the language generated by $\sigma$?

**Edit**. To facilitate ease of expression, feel free to use the phrase *literal sentence* to mean 'a sentence that is either atomic, or the negation of a sentence that is atomic.'

**Edit2**. If it helps, here's some terminology we can use.

```
concept                    generic example

atomic          sentence   2<3
literal         sentence   not 3<2
quantifier-free sentence   if 2<3 and 3<4, then 2<4.
                sentence   For all x,y,z : if x<y and y<z, then x<z.

atomic          formula    2<x.
literal         formula    not 2<x.
quantifier-free formula    if x<y and y<z, then x<z.
                formula    For all x : if x<y and y<z, then x<z.
```

Comment: If you wanted to replace the talk of structures with that of diagrams, then you still need to have a definition for a structure, because the diagram is defined in terms of structures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We could, if we liked, replace the notion of structure with the purely syntactic notion of diagram... but we'd have to be careful about what we meant by diagram.

Here's a reasonable definition. Given a language $\mathcal{L}$ and a set of constants $A$ (disjoint from $\mathcal{L}$), I'll denote by $\mathcal{L}(A)$ the language obtained by adding the constants in $A$ to $\mathcal{L}$. When I say a quantifier-free theory $T$ is complete, I just mean that for every quantifier free sentence $\phi$, $\phi\in T$ or $\lnot\phi\in T$.

Definition: In a language $\mathcal{L}$, a *diagram* on the set of constants $A$ is a complete consistent quantifier-free $\mathcal{L}(A)$-theory $T$ satisfying closure in the following sense:

1. Given an $n$-ary function $f$ in $\mathcal{L}$ and constants $a_1,\dots,a_n$ from $A$, there is a constant $a$ from $A$ such that the sentence $f(a_1,\dots,a_n) = a$ is in $T$.
2. Given a constant symbol $c$ in $\mathcal{L}$, there is a constant $a$ from $A$ such that the sentence $c = a$ is in $T$.

Now every $\mathcal{L}$-structure $A$ gives rise to a diagram in the usual way (taking the quantifier-free $\mathcal{L}(A)$-theory of $A$).

Conversely, given a diagram in the sense above, we can obtain a structure. I think this is where the previous answers (due to William and Alex Kocurek) misunderstood your question - it's true that a diagram doesn't have a unique model, but if it's closed in the sense above, it determines a *canonical model*.

Take the domain of the structure to be the quotient of the set $A$ by the equivalence relation $\sim$, where $a\sim b$ if and only if the sentence $a = b$ is in $T$. I'll denote by $[a]$ the equivalence class of $a$. Then interpret the constants and relations as dictated by the theory $T$ (of course, there's a well-definedness check to do):

- $c^A = [a]$ if $c = a$ is in $T$ (using closure)
- $f^A([a_1],\dots,[a_n]) = [a]$ if $f(a_1,\dots,a_n)=a\in T$ (using closure)
- $R^A([a_1],\dots,[a_n])$ if and only if $R(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in T$

A few observations:

1. This is the same "canonical model" construction appearing in Henkin's proof of the Completeness Theorem. There, too, we're interested in obtaining a structure from a suitable theory.
2. If you want to avoid the quotient, you can additionally require in the definition of diagram that $\lnot a = b$ is in $T$ for all $a\neq b$. This has the advantage of making the constructions inverses - the diagram associated to the structure associated to a diagram is the original diagram and vice versa.
3. This is all a little silly. We're just replacing the usual notion of structure, an arbitrary set together with interpretations of the symbols, with an arbitrary set of constants together with a syntactic description of how the symbols are to be interpreted.

But now for your last question: how do you define satisfaction in this setup? Given a diagram $D$ on the constants $A$, we'll define what it means for $D$ to satisfy $\phi(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, where $\phi$ is an $\mathcal{L}$-formula and the $a_i$ are constants from $A$.

An atomic formula should obviously be satisfied by $D$ if and only if it is in $D$. The definition for Boolean combinations is as usual. So we only need to worry about $\exists$. Well, since the constants in $A$ are the elements of the structure $D$ is describing, we say $D$ satisfies $\exists x\,\phi(x,a_1,\dots,a_n)$ if and only if there is a constant $a\in A$ such that $D$ satisfies $\phi(a,a_1,\dots,a_n)$.

Comment: Yes, that's a much better answer. :)

Comment: Alex thanks for your answer. I'm curious, why are you basing everything around quantifier-free sentences? Note that 'quantifier-free sentence' is a less stringent condition than 'atomic sentence'.

Comment: Actually, I have just noticed we're probably interested in 'atomic or negated atomic' sentences, rather than just the atomic ones. Anyway, note that this is still more stringent condition than just 'quantifier-free sentence' For instance, $((2<3) \wedge (3<4)) \rightarrow (2<3)$ is a quantifier free sentence, but is it neither an atomic sentence nor a negated atomic sentence.

Comment: P.S. I edited the question, stating that: "To facilitate ease of expression, feel free to use the phrase *literal sentence* to mean a sentence that is either atomic, or the negation of a sentence that is atomic."

Comment: @user18921 Ah yes, I had forgotten that the diagram of a structure usually consists of all literal sentences in its theory, not all quantifier free sentences. It's reasonable that I had forgotten this, because the two notions of diagram are equivalent: Every literal is quantifier free, and if you know the truth value of every atomic sentence, then you know the truth value of every quantifier free sentence, since a quantifier free sentence is just a boolean combination of atomic sentences, i.e. the "literal diagram" generates the "quantifier free diagram".

Comment: Feel free to read my answer replacing "quantifier free" with "literal" everywhere you see it. Everything will still work out.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram does not determine the structure. Even stronger, the full theory of a structure does not determine a structure.

There are elementarily equivalent structures that are not isomorphic. In fact, if you take any structure of uncountable cardinality in a countable language, by the downward Lowenheim Skolem, you can get a countable elementary substructure. Hence the two structure has the same diagram (in fact full theory), but there are no isomorphism between the two just by cardinality consideration.

Comment: William I think you have misread the definition! The diagram is written in the *extended* language generated by $\sigma'$; this means that, in particular, we have a constant symbol for each element of $X$.

Comment: Yes, but there is no guarantee that every element in a model of the diagram is the interpretation of a constant!

Comment: @ZhenLin Then for such a model $\mathfrak M$ of the diagram $D$ in a language $\mathcal L$, wouldn't we have $D \subsetneq \mathrm{diag}_{\mathfrak M}$ in the language $\mathcal L_M$ (extended language with constant for each element of the base $M$ of $\mathfrak M$)  ? If so, William's argument doesn't hold.

Comment: I think everyone is misunderstanding the question... see my answer.

Comment: To say that the diagram $D$ of a structure $\mathfrak A$ determines the structure does not mean that $\mathfrak A$ is the only model of $D$ (which is in fact false) but rather than $\mathfrak A$ is the only structure (up to isomorphism) whose diagram is $D$ (which is true).

Answer (score 0):

As William has correctly noted, the diagram certainly *does not* determine the structure in question. True, it tells you every atomic thing that's true or false about the element of the original model (say $\cal{A}$), but there are other models with *more* structure which could satisfy that diagram (for instance, by including elements which aren't named in the diagram). In fact, it's a theorem of model theory that if $\cal{A},\cal{B}$ are models, with $A \subseteq B$, then $\cal{A}$ is a substructure of $\cal{B}$ if and only if $\cal{B}$ satisfies the diagram of $\cal{A}$. Hence, all superstructures of $\cal{A}$ will satisfy the diagram as well, but they certainly need not be isomorphic.

For instance, take a simple model where you have two elements $a,b \in A$, and let's say we have a unary predicate $P$ whose interpretation in $\cal{A}$ is $P^\mathcal{A} = \{a,b\}$. Then, $\mathcal{A} \vDash \forall x P(x)$. But now consider an extension of $\cal{A}$, $\cal{B}$ with one extra element $c \in B - A$, but with the interpretation of $P$ the same. Then $\mathcal{B} \vDash \text{diag}(\mathcal{A})$ (when you extend the language of $\cal{B}$ to what you're calling $\sigma'$), so $\cal{A} \subseteq \cal{B}$, and yet $\mathcal{B} \vDash \neg\forall x P(x)$ since $\mathcal{B} \vDash \neg P[c]$. So $\cal{A}$ and $\cal{B}$ aren't even elementarily equivalent!

Also, to answer your last question, a structure satisfies a theory just in case it satisfies each sentence of a theory. Satisfaction of sentences in models is defined in the usual inductive way.